# scrollIntoView vs moveToElement

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In Selenium WebDriver, there are two major methods to *put an element into a visible area*:

1. [Scrolling into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

   ```
   ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
   ```
2. Using [`moveToElement` browser action](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-):

   ```
   Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
   actions.moveToElement(element);
   actions.perform();
   ```

Are these methods equivalent and which one should be preferred?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

#### `scrollIntoView`

The DOM method `scrollIntoView` only scrolls the element into view. If `scrollIntoView` cannot scroll the element into view, it will just fail silently.I added an invisible element to the start of `body` and called `scrollIntoView` on it. Nothing scrolled but there was no error. Note that you have more control on *how* the element is scrolled with `scrollIntoView` than with `moveToElement`. Selenium is only interested in bringing the element into view so that the mouse can be placed on it. It does not give you any say in how it is going to do it. `scrollIntoView` however allows you, for instance, to specify whether you want the top or bottom of the element to be align with its scrollable ancestor. (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for the details.)

#### `moveToElement`

The Selenium method `moveToElement` does two things: it scrolls the element into view and moves the mouse on top of the element. I've also tested it with elements that cannot be scrolled or moved to because they have no coordinates on screen and got no error here either.

#### Choosing One

I default to using `moveToElement`, with the following exceptions:

- If you do not want to affect at all where Selenium has placed the mouse but you want to scroll something into view (a bit strange... but possible), then you should use `scrollIntoView`.
- If you need to scroll an element with the kind of control that `scrollIntoView` gives you (like the alignment option I mentioned above), then you have to use it rather than `moveToElement`.
- There are cases where trying to simulate user behavior through Selenium's commands is not possible or is very expensive to do by sending a series of Selenium commands. (Each command is a round-trip to the network. When the testing server somewhere across the Internet, it adds up.) In such cases, I use Selenium's `executeScript`. In such case, it can be advantageous to use `scrollIntoView` in the script being executed, rather then end the script, create an `Action` to perform the scroll, and finish the whole operation with another `executeScript`.

Comment: moveToElement don't scroll to the element if it is not visible on screen. It only controls the mouse and put the cursor on the element. If you want to scroll to an invisible element, you'll have to tell selenium to scroll the page until the element position is visible on the screen (you can compare element location with viewport)

Comment: So far have see that JS scrollIntoView always works, but Actions moveTo fails. Why does JS seem to be more reliable ?