# ScrollIntoView is not working properly if element is up - Selenium?

Tags: selenium

Scroll to element works fine if element is lower position ( scroll down ) , but in case of element is upper position ( scroll up ) it don't scroll to element in view rather it scroll one less to element ( count is not fixed may it 2 or 3 , varies ) .

I have to write explicit code for scroll up for element which is up , after ScrollIntoView , this is not consistent as scroll up count is not fixed .

I used this 2 codes one by  one , but both gives same behavior

Code1 :

```
            // Scroll to view by Action 
            Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
            actions.MoveToElement(webElement);
            actions.Perform();
```

Code 2:

```
            // Scroll to view by JavaScript executer     
   ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", webElement);
```

Please help me in this case , please suggest what I have to with this .

Comment: Referrence: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement" You have more control on how the element is scrolled with scrollIntoView than with moveToElement. Selenium is only interested in bringing the element into view so that the mouse can be placed on it. It does not give you any say in how it is going to do it. scrollIntoView however allows you, for instance, to specify whether you want the top or bottom of the element to be align with its scrollable ancestor. Check this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: @Abhinav, thank you very much  :) , it working fine after reading above reference and applying to my scenario .

Comment: I will add this as answer. Please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referrence: [scrollIntoView vs moveToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement%22)
 You have more control on how the element is scrolled with `scrollIntoView` than with `moveToElement`. 
Selenium is only interested in bringing the element into view so that the mouse can be placed on it. It does not give you any say in how it is going to do it. `scrollIntoView` however allows you, for instance, to specify whether you want the top or bottom of the element to be align with its scrollable ancestor. 
Check this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Answer (score 0):

You can try double `MoveToElement()`. First scroll to the element parent and than to the element itself

```
actions.MoveToElement(parentElement).MoveToElement(webElement).Perform();
```