# How to scroll top of browser window from middle or bottom of browser window using javascript in protractor

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, protractor

I need to `click` the `element` located at bottom of page then I have to `click` `element` located at top of page.

i.e **scroll up** which is not visible to browser.

For scroll down I've used:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove(element).perform()`"
```

Kindly suggest solution to do this task

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to scroll to the very top of the page:

1. Via `window.scrollTo()`:

   ```
   browser.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, 0);");
   ```
2. Locate an element on top and *scroll into it's view*:

   ```
   var header = element(by.tagName("header"));
   browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", header.getWebElement());
   ```
3. Locate an element on top and move to it as you've demonstrated for the scroll down:

   ```
   var header = element(by.tagName("header"));
   browser.actions().mouseMove(header).perform();
   ```

Also see:

- [scrollIntoView vs moveToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement)