# How can I scroll to the location of a page where an element is visible with Selenium using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

I am currently using the following piece of code to navigate to the middle of the page but it is not working properly.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/2);")
```

Also, I am trying to use

```
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

You may call `.scrollIntoView()` in your script passing in your element as an argument:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

There is also `move_to_element()` built-in selenium action:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

The differences were perfectly highlighted here:

- [scrollIntoView vs moveToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34562095/771848)