# Perform TAB action until active element is the required element - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to perform TAB action until I have reached a particular web-element. Until the active element is the below mentioned element, TAB action has to be performed.

```
>name = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
>name.send_keys("ABC")
>group = driver.find_element_by_name("group") 
>group.send_keys("DEF")
```

I am able to find element till the above state. After that, I want to perform TAB action until the below mentioned element is found. I guess using a loop would help.

> elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PeriodCell input')

Please find below the HTML code

```
<div class="PeriodCell" style="left:px; width:112px;">
<div class="Effort forecasting">
<div class="entity field-value-copy-selected">
<input type="text" value="0.0" data-start="2014-09-20">
</div>
</div>
<div class="Effort unmet zero" title="">0.0
</div>
</div>
```

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why u need a tab action to click on that element?

Comment: for tab action `from pywinauto.keyboard import SendKeys` `SendKeys("TAB ,number of the tab")`

Comment: I perform tab action to move from that element to the next element. I want to keep doing the same until I have reached the below element
> elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PeriodCell input')

Comment: u can directly go to that element without tab action

Comment: I tried that. There is a horizontal scroll bar at that place and the bar is moved little towards the right by default. So the element is hidden. I got the below error,

ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: can u provide url

Comment: elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('PeriodCell').click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform `TAB Action` until you find a particular *WebElement* would not be as per the *best practices*. As per your comment *the element is hidden* so you need to bring the element within the [**Viewport**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) first and then invoke `click()`/`send_keys()` as follows:

```
myElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='PeriodCell']//input[@type='text'][@value=\"0.0\"]")
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", myElement)
# perfrom any action on the element
```

However the alternative using the `TAB Action` is as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

global element
element = driver.find_element_by_name("name")
element.send_keys("ABC")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("group") 
element.send_keys("DEF")
while True:
    element.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
    element = driver.switch_to_active_element()
    if (element.get_attribute("type")=='text' and element.get_attribute("value")=='0.0' and element.get_attribute("data-start")=='2014-09-20'):
    print("Element found")
    break
# do anythin with the element
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the element to the visible part of the screen by using one of the following methods.

1. Using `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)`
   you can read more about `scrollIntoView()` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).
2. Using the Actions class of selenium webdriver.

from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.PeriodCell input')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

You can read the difference between these two methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35090932/5074293)

If you still need to use the TAB action to reach the element

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

and using `.send_keys(Keys.TAB)` send the TAB key to the element

Comment: I am getting this error
ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Comment: @Abraham : There are 3 approaches in my answer. Which approach in particular gives you this error?