# How to click on a button in a Alert?

Tags: java, selenium

i have to automate [this page](https://signup.insly.com/signup) using `java` ,and `selenium`.
I must click on the link which has label `terms and conditions` it shows up a box, and then i need to navigate it down, and click on Agree button.

[image]

I have already tried:

```
        driver.click("//*[@id=\"field_terms\"]/td[2]/div/div/label[1]/a");  // Click on the link
```

it opens the box for me, but i stuck after it.

I have 2 problems:

1. How to scrol down the pop up?
2. How to click on the ***Agree*** button?

**Update:**

Regarding the scroll problem i used the below method which does not work:

```
public void scrollDown() {
        JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jsx.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1];","window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
    }
```

Comment: That's not a JS alert so `Alert` won't work on it. It's HTML like the rest of the page. Post the relevant HTML for the I AGREE button and we can help.

Comment: @JeffC sorry, but how do you identify it is not an alert, which is changed by `css`?

Comment: You should take a look at different JS alerts. It doesn't look anything like them. One way you can confirm this is to right-click on it and see if you get a context menu and can inspect the HTML. If you can, then you know it's not a JS alert.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the CSS Selector to locate the I Agree button

```
'div[class="ui-dialog-buttonset"]>button[btnclass="primary"]'
```

It worked in my system. I am not a Java person, this is the code I wrote in python for your reference

```
driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://signup.insly.com/signup')

terms_and_conditions = driver.find_element_by_link_text('terms and conditions')
terms_and_conditions.click()

import time
time.sleep(2)

i_agree = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
              'div[class="ui-dialog-buttonset"]>button[btnclass="primary"]'
          )
i_agree.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the scroll: just use JavaScript...

```
JavascriptExecutor jsx = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jsx.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,450)", "");
```

Or you can just scroll up to the element needed...

`((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", your_WebElement);`

For the click 'I agree' use XPATH like this:
`"//*[text()='I AGREE']"` then just preform `click()`

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks, i am more intersted to fix the Button problem. i have updated my question with your answer, and the new error which i got

Comment: @KamyarParastesh I'll try again tomorrow... Hope you find a solution quick!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code in Java [Tested & worked].

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://signup.insly.com/signup");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("terms and conditions")).click();
    //Click the I AGREE button
    WebElement btnIagree = driver
            .findElement(By.xpath("//button[@btnclass='primary' and contains(text(),'I agree')]"));
    btnIagree.click();
    //Verify the check box for T&C is checked
    WebElement chkbxTnC=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='agree_termsandconditions']/../span[@class='icon-check-empty icon-check']"));
    Assert.assertTrue(chkbxTnC.isDisplayed());
```

The problem is, as soon as you click on the T&C link, it takes few seconds to load the page and since a wait is needed before hitting the I AGREE Button. Apparently, the I AGREE Button is enabled and clickable without the need of scrolling down, so scrolling is not needed here.

Comment: how do you scroll down?

Comment: To scroll down / to make the elemet to visible, refer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement