# Can selenium find_element_by_xpath in outlook online?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm having trouble finding elements by xpath or id inside of outlook's online html.  I'm using selenium and python.  Here is what I've wrote.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException #imports

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\...')
browser.get('https://www.office.com/...') #setup

#then some code to sign into outlook online

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_ariaId_64"]/div/div/div[1]')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="MailFolderPane.FavoritesFolders"]/div[19]')

browser.find_element_by_id('_ariaId_68') #attempts to find an element in outlook
```

this is the element I'm trying to access.  I would post the entire html, but there is just so much.  I'm brand new to all things code so go easy on me :)

```
<div>
   <div id="_ariaId_68" aria-expanded="false" draggable="true" dropzone="string:text/plain">
      <div autoid="_n_R" class="_n_44 canShowFavoritesAction" role="treeitem" aria-expanded="false" aria-labelledby="_ariaId_68.folder _ariaId_68.ucount" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1">
         <div class="_n_S3 nowrap border-color-transparent _n_X3" style="padding-left: 4px;">
            <div class="_n_V3 _n_54">
               <span autoid="_n_S" class="_n_W3 ms-font-m ms-fwt-sl _n_Y3" id="_ariaId_68.folder" title="Sent Items">Sent Items</span>  
               <div class="_n_24 ms-bg-color-neutralLighter"> <span autoid="_n_T" class="ms-font-m _n_Z3 ms-fwt-sb ms-fcl-tp" aria-hidden="true"></span> </div>
               <span class="ms-font-s ms-fcl-ns" aria-hidden="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" tabindex="-1">  </span>   <button autoid="_n_U" type="button" class="_n_34 ms-fwt-r ms-fcl-ns o365button hidden" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1"></button>  <span style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
            </div>
            <div class="_n_14 hidden"><button autoid="_n_V" type="button" class="_n_04 firefoxFavorite o365button" title="Remove from Favorites" aria-labelledby="_ariaId_69"><span class="_fc_3 owaimg ms-Icon--star ms-icon-font-size-18 ms-fcl-ns-b"> </span><span class="_fc_4 o365buttonLabel _fc_2" id="_ariaId_69" style="display: none;"></span></button></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The subtance of your post is not bad, but could you please format it better? For example organize it better instead of a bunch of random headers and format the code so that is not basic text. Take a look here for help https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, B. Cratty.  Also thanks for editing, Lucas Wieloch.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to find the *SENT ITEMS*'s - web element.

The SENT ITEM link does not seem to be the visible area  [when you have more sub folders inside Inbox, this usually happens] and hence you first make a scroll to view to the element before performing anything on the element.

[Here are the options to bring the element to visible area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34562095/scrollintoview-vs-movetoelement)

Try with following xpath
`//span[@title='Sent Items']`

Comment: Okay, I tried the sent items path.  It still didn't work.  I think I need to do some research on finding iframes.  I know there are a lot in the html, and I may be trying to work with code that is inside of one.  Its just that my elemeny inspector won't show any iframes unless I search for them in the search bar, and then it is impossible to navigate back to the original path.  Its just a really large confusing code, so I need to figure out what the real path is somehow.